# Share image through whatsApp html5

Tags: javascript

How to share the website captured image through whatsApp using JS. I used the following code

```
var message="Sample Text";
window.location.href= "whatsapp://send?text="+message;
```

Through which i'm able to share only the text but i want to share the image.Can anyone please help regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013), the WhatsApp URL scheme only supports one parameter, that is `text`. So it's either not possible at all, or not documented and you'd have to try out different approaces like `img=` or `image=` followed by an image URL or base64 encoded image data.

But as matters stand now: It's not supported. *

* That is, from the context of a website. As the FAQ also states, you can use Share Extensions to share various kinds of data. But your question implies that you are looking for a web solution.